# Using SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE in VC++ 6.0

Tags: winapi, sockets, visual-c++

I am trying to build my exe win32 app that has to use SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option through setsockopt . But When i build my exe in VC++ , it wudnt compile as it says this symbol is undeclared . Similar symbols like SO_REUSEADDR has been defined in vc98/include/winsock2.h .  Any insights as to how to get this thing compiled . What version of winsock libraries support this exclusive address stuff . If i replace the corresponding header file and library in vc98 , will this be able to run in  compatible way ??

Happiness,
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the latest Windows SDK - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924

`SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` didn't exist when VC6 was shipped and so isn't in the headers that were supplied with it.